# Archaic way of describing the one who never kills / slays

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Want to address a character (in 3rd person).

That character has lied several times so cannot be [immaculate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/immaculate) (as I thought it would be). Any word which is **less filtered** than immaculate?

This character does not kill and will never, not sworn but ethically he finds it wrong to kill anybody.

Not necessarily one word... Could be 2 words or 3, but this is just an addressal, shorter the better.

To make it easier, how would you describe a medieval Batman? Wears an armor and carries a sword but does not kill and never will.

PS: He isn't a vigilante.

Comment: Medieval Batman, that would be awesome!

Comment: One who believes in the **sanctity of life**

Comment: Nonkilling knight, Knight with a no-kill rule.

Comment: Yes... Person *who believes in sanctity of life* Oh wait! @NVZ I guess you are right.. That is exactly how I will describe him. Make it an answer here.

Comment: Btw.. is there a single word for it?

Comment: @NVZ: Medieval Batman = Dracula + soul? Sounds like the latest spin-off from *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*. Get Hollywood on the phone!

Comment: @Scott it's actually an old concept. There are some comics existing with such themes. :)

Comment: @NVZ Hmm... Interesting... Example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*It's a roundabout answer, but OP asked me to post this.*</sub>

**Nonkilling** — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonkilling)

> *adjective (not comparable)*
>   Not engaging in killing.
>
> *noun ‎(usually uncountable, plural nonkillings)*
>   1. A precept or worldview that affirms the possibility of a society where killing is absent.
>   2. Lack of killing; permitting to live.

The knight with a no-kill rule (or the [nonkilling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonkilling) knight) believes in the **right to life** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_life)

> The right to life is a moral principle based on the belief that a human being has the right to live and, in particular, should not be killed by another human being.
>
> The concept of a right to life arises in debates on issues of capital punishment, war, abortion, euthanasia, justifiable homicide and, by extension, public health care.

Or believes in the **sanctity of life** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctity_of_life)

> In religion and ethics, inviolability or sanctity of life is a principle of implied protection regarding aspects of sentient life which are said to be holy, sacred, or otherwise of such value that they are not to be violated.

Comment: "sanctity of life" fits well with the way the character is described. Thank you Ultron.

Comment: @Karma It's funny that I'm Ultron. I personally believe humanity should go extinct. ;)

Comment: Let philosophers debate on that! We may have out-lived our extinction time-frame but I also believe that Humans are the top predators and we do not have mortal enemies... Maybe that is the reason humans kill one another.

Comment: Ironic as it may seem... but, there are words for `the one who kills` in almost every language but not for the one who chooses not to kill. OK Ultron... I gotta go.. Hail Hydra.